# unusual bash array command

Tags: arrays, bash

Found this snippet of code which uses an array in Bash.

```
unset var1[@]

for i in {0..23}
do
    var1[10#$i]="some data"
done
```

When setting the element with data, what's that `10#` in front of the element number for?

I know that for showing the total number of elements you can use `echo ${#var1[@]}` but I don't think the hash in setting the element has something to do with total size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In arithmetic expressions, you can use `#` to specify **base**:

```
$ echo $((2#1110))
14
```

Using `10#$i` would prevent `i=08` from failing with `value too great for base` and interpret it as `8`. For 0 .. 23, it's equivalent to just `i`.

Comment: That is bizarre.. I never would have guessed it. Yup, without 10# the i=07 goes fine and i=08 fails with "-bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")". Whoa... So pardon my ignorance, what is the default base for defining the array element number then?

Comment: Decimal, but the shell would automatically interpret it as octal if the number starts by '0'. Is the same that the leading '0x' for hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: I'm gonna chmod myself outta here.. Thanks all...  :-)

Comment: You can use it for bases from 2 to 64. Nice: `echo $((50#A0))` will print `1800` (50*36) and `echo $((64#_0))` `4032`.